# How to use c3 library for shiny? How to create a simple gauge chart?

Tags: r, shiny, c3.js, gauge

How should i use c3 library? I have already installed it and is trying to display a simple gauge chart.

Below is my code for `ui.R` and `server.R` :

`server.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(c3)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {


observeEvent(input$button, {

output$name <- renderText({
paste("Welcome ",input$name,". This is your Assesment result!")})
output$nl <- renderText({input$nl})

whrs <- input$whrs

if(whrs == 10) {
  point <- 20
} else if (whrs == 8 || whrs == 9) {
  point <- 18
} else if (whrs == 7 || whrs == 6) {
  point <- 12
} else if(whrs == 5) {
  point <- 8
} else {

point <- 0
}

pwhrs <- point
nl <- input$nl

if(nl == 10) {
  point <- 20
} else if (nl == 8 || whrs == 9) {
  point <- 18
} else if (nl == 7 || whrs == 6) {
  point <- 12
} else if(nl == 5) {
  point <- 8
} else {

point <- 0
}
pnl <- point


output$pwhrs <- renderText({pwhrs})
output$pnl <- renderText({pnl})

output$plot <- renderPlot({
gauge.chart <- data.frame(red=20,green=45,blue=10) %>% 
  c3() %>% 
c3_gauge(title= 'Colours')

})
})

})
```

and my `ui.R`

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  hr(),
titlePanel("Summary"),
hr(),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  textInput("name","Enter your name",""),
numericInput("whrs","How many hours do you work daily?","0",min=0,max=10),
numericInput("nl","How many leaves do you take per month?","0",min= 0,max=20),
numericInput("bhr","How many hours of break do you take daily?","0",min= 0,max=10),
selectInput("wrkdlvr","How often you complete your works?",choices=c("On time","Before Deadline","Delayed")),
selectInput("consleave","How often you leaves are consecutive?",choices=c("Never","Always","Not Applicable")),
actionButton("button", "Calculate")
),
  mainPanel(("About this tool"),
   p(helpText("Try this tool to assess yourself.
    You need to work for a minimum of 9 hrs per day.")),
helpText("This tool will ask for some parameters and based on the input you will 
  be assessed"),
hr(),
  textOutput("name"),
textOutput("pwhrs"),
textOutput("pnl"),
plotOutput("plot"),
  hr()
  )
  ),
hr()
))
```

What has to be done to produce a simple gauge chart based on user input? max limit for a chart is 100 and based on user input the value to be shown is set. How to achieve this?

Is it necessary to add c3 library in both `ui.R` and `server.R`? ( Please tell me whether is it needed to add any additional library used in both files.)

Is `shiny` and `shinydashboard` libraries almost same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `renderC3` instead of `renderPlot` in the server, and `c3Output` instead of `plotOutput` in the ui.

`shinydashboard` differ from `shiny` mostly in the UI appearance (the ui script will be also different), the logic behind is the same.

If want to give it a try, i wrote a package very similar to `c3`, [`billboarder`](https://github.com/dreamRs/billboarder), you can also do gauge chart, you can install it with :

```
devtools::install_github("dreamRs/billboarder")
```

And with your example it gives (I put the outputs outside the observer, it's a better practice, and use `reactiveValues` to store the number of points) :

```
library("shiny")
library("billboarder")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidPage(
    hr(),
    titlePanel("Summary"),
    hr(),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        textInput("name","Enter your name",""),
        numericInput("whrs","How many hours do you work daily?","0", min = 0, max = 10),
        numericInput("nl","How many leaves do you take per month?","0", min = 0, max = 20),
        numericInput("bhr","How many hours of break do you take daily?","0", min = 0,max = 10),
        selectInput("wrkdlvr","How often you complete your works?", choices = c("On time", "Before Deadline", "Delayed")),
        selectInput("consleave", "How often you leaves are consecutive?", choices = c("Never", "Always", "Not Applicable")),
        actionButton("button", "Calculate")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        "About this tool",
        p(helpText("Try this tool to assess yourself.",
                   "You need to work for a minimum of 9 hrs per day.")),
        helpText("This tool will ask for some parameters and based on the input you will",
                 "be assessed"),
        hr(),
        textOutput(outputId = "name"),
        textOutput(outputId = "pwhrs"),
        textOutput(outputId = "pnl"),
        billboarderOutput(outputId = "gauge"),
        hr()
      )
    ),
    hr()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$name <- renderText({
    paste0("Welcome ", input$name, ". This is your Assesment result!")
  })
  output$nl <- renderText({input$nl})

  points <- reactiveValues(pwhrs = 0, pnl = 0)

  observeEvent(input$button, {
    whrs <- input$whrs

    if(whrs == 10) {
      point <- 20
    } else if (whrs == 8 | whrs == 9) {
      point <- 18
    } else if (whrs == 7 | whrs == 6) {
      point <- 12
    } else if(whrs == 5) {
      point <- 8
    } else {

      point <- 0
    }

    points$pwhrs <- point
    nl <- input$nl

    if(nl == 10) {
      point <- 20
    } else if (nl == 8 | nl == 9) {
      point <- 18
    } else if (nl == 7 | nl == 6) {
      point <- 12
    } else if(nl == 5) {
      point <- 8
    } else {
      point <- 0
    }
    points$pnl <- point
  })

  output$pwhrs <- renderText({points$pwhrs})
  output$pnl <- renderText({points$pnl})


  output$gauge <- renderBillboarder({
    billboarder() %>% 
      bb_gaugechart(value = points$pnl + points$pwhrs)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Nice Package `billboarder` u created, its the first time I hear about it, I will definitely add it to my repertoire. Do you have examples of real-time rendering with static HTML such as those created with `rmarkdown` ?

Comment: Thanks! That's nice to hear! The package is recent, i started two month ago, i'll plan to run some tests this week and go to CRAN early september. I've uploaded an example on Rpubs : http://rpubs.com/Victorp/billboarder_examples , if you use it, let me know !